# Elastic Image Slideshow autoplay resume after thumbnail clicked

Tags: javascript

Hi I am using Elastic Image Slideshow downloaded from here:

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ElasticSlideshow/index2.html

But the autoplay will stop after the thumbnail is clicked. I wonder how to resume the autoplay again after some seconds. I saw this code in js:

```
    // click the thumbs
        this.$thumbs.on( 'click.eislideshow', function( event ) {

            if( _self.options.autoplay ) {

                clearTimeout( _self.slideshow );
                _self.options.autoplay  = false;

            }

            var $thumb  = $(this),
                idx     = $thumb.index() - 1; // exclude sliding div

            _self._slideTo( idx );

            return false;

        });
```

I wonder how to modify it. Let the autoplay resume after 5 second or certain duration i specify. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by adding the following code after the `_self.options.autoplay  = false;` line:

```
setTimeout( function() { 
                        _self.options.autoplay  = true;
                        _self._startSlideshow();
            }, 5000); //restart autoplay after 5 seconds
```

that should do what you want.